# In Bash, how do I repeat a series of commands with a word substitute

Tags: command-line, bash

What I'm looking for is something that would perform a series of commands like this:

```
# cat file1 >> concated_file
# cat file2 >> concated_file
# cat file3 >> concated_file
# cat file4 >> concated_file
```

But  wouldn't require me to retype the whole command 3 additional times. Maybe just be able to replace the argument from the previous command with syntax like the following:

```
# cat file1 >> concated_file
# s/file1/file2
# s/file2/file3
# s/file3/file4
```

I know that if the last argument is the same you could do this:

```
# cp -p test1.txt test2.txt
# chmod 777 $_
# chown nimmylebby: $_
```

And you could also use Bash loops like so:

```
# for f in 'file1' 'file2'; 
> do 
> chmod 750 $f;
> done
```

However, the above 2 examples are **not** what I'm looking. I just want to perform a series of commands which only differ by one argument **without** using for loops. Is this possible? Might not be but hoping it is ;-).

Comment: at least for me it is not clear of what you want to do ...

Comment: Heh guess it's you + atleast another person. I'll try to add more clarification in the last "looking for" example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Press <kbd>Up</kbd>, edit the command as necessary, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- As previously, but arrange for the changing word to come last in the command for easier edition, e.g., `cat >> concated_file file1`. This is straightforward with your example command, not so in all cases.
- Define a function taking the variable part as an argument: `f () { cat "$1" >> concated_file; }`. Then invoke the function several times: `f file1`, `f file2`, …
- Use [history expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#History-Interaction). Here you can do `^file1^file2`.

Comment: Left the best for last huh? History expansion is *exactly* what I was looking for. Thanks!!

Comment: History expansion is awesome, +1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you need is a function:

```
function mycat() { cat $1 >> concated_file; }
mycat file1
mycat file2
mycat file3
mycat file4
```